# Uploading a model to synapse

Tags: r, open-source, machine-learning

I tried to upload a data model to Synapse, and I got the following error message (from remote console):

```
Error in if (grepl("/$", filePath)) { : argument is of length zero In
addition: Warning messages: 1: In file.copy(object$getCacheDir(),
path, recursive = TRUE) : problem creating directory
/home/creighto@bcm.edu/scratch/tmp/RtmpHjLEQh/cacheRoot5e4dbe7c02d/archive.zip_unpacked/.R_OBJECTS:
No space left on device 2: In unzip(filename, exdir = destdir) : error
1 in extracting from zip file.
```

Also my directory has frozen up, and I cannot seem to access files. Have I exceeded a space limit here?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to state the obvious, but it does look like you've ran out of space: you can't unzip file due to space, so you can't create a directory. Can you reduce the file size?